# How to reduce turn around time of Livy

Tags: apache-spark, hortonworks-data-platform, livy

In my application I submit spark job through livy and  get back the result by uploading the jar file every time to the cluster, but the problem is it takes 20 seconds to give the results back. Is there any way I could reduce the time taken by livy server to give back the job results ?

Kindly shed some light on repl in livy.

Livy version - 0.5.0
HDP - 3.0.1.0
Spark - 2.3.1